# Substitution variables are empty when cloud build was triggered from github

Tags: github, google-cloud-build

My cloud build trigger has some substitution variables and set on web console.
When i run trigger on web console manually, it works well.
but trigger from github, substitution variables are empty.
how can i set substitution variables when github trigger my builds?

Following is part of my cloudbuild.yaml.

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/kubectl'
  args: ['apply', '-f', 'service/k8s']
  env:
  - 'CLOUDSDK_COMPUTE_ZONE=${_ZONE}'
  - 'CLOUDSDK_CONTAINER_CLUSTER=${_CLUSTER_NAME}'
```

[screenshot of my substitution variables on trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gssgu.png)

Comment: Can you share your trigger config and your cloud build file?

Comment: i added my conf and screenshot to my question. can you check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce this issue. Try to add a step like this for validating what are the substitutions performed.

```
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args: ['-c', 'printenv | grep CLOUDSDK']
    env:
      - 'CLOUDSDK_COMPUTE_ZONE=${_ZONE}'
      - CLOUDSDK_CONTAINER_CLUSTER=${_CLUSTER_NAME}
```

Here I grep only the env var which contain `CLOUDSDK`.

I try with and without the simple quote around the env var, with and without [substitutions section](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values#using_user-defined_substitutions). In all cases, it works with manual launch and GitHub event launch.

Check also that is the right trigger which is called (if you have several, disable all except this one)

Comment: it's weird, now my trigger is working well without any changes...
anyway, thank you for your help.

Comment: Don't worry. Keep the tips with the entry point for running any linux command and check what's going. `ls` is often useful!